# Question with how sample code works (LeetCode Question)

Tags: c

recently I was working on a LeetCode medium question, **Longest Substring without Repeating Characters**, and got stuck so I looked at a sample solution.

(Goal is to find length of longest substring in a string)

Could someone please explain how the following code works? I understand that it is using an array to remember every character and track the occurances, but I don't understand the body fully.

```
int lengthOfLongestSubstring(char * s){

    int tmp[256] = {0};

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
        tmp[i] = -1;

    int max_len = 0, start = -1;
    int i;

    if (*s == '\0')
        return 0;

    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char c = s[i];
        if (tmp[c] >= start) {
            start = tmp[c] + 1;
        }
    
        max_len = i - start + 1 > max_len ? i - start + 1 : max_len; 
        tmp[c] = i;
    }

    max_len = i - start > max_len ? i - start : max_len;
    return max_len;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really suited to explaining whole blocks of code. But basically that code uses `tmp` to track the index of when each character is last seen. `start` is the start index of the current candidate sub-string. `if (tmp[c] >= start)` checks whether the current character has already been seen in the current sub-string. If it has then start a new candidate sub-string because the character is repeated in the previous sub-string.

Comment: A debugger, single-stepping that for-loop, and watching what is stored in `tmp` with each iteration, will be highly educational. Debuggers aren't just for finding bugs; they can divulge a wealth of information about how existing code works.

Comment: @kaylum the explanation helped a lot! thanks

Comment: @WhozCraig i tried your suggestion on this prob and a following one, helped a lot too for grasping the general idea.